# Symfony 2 Routing - Prefix for optional parameters

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing

### Problem to solve

I have a url with prefixed parameters. I need this for some SEO reasons, but i can't create a complete slug like foo-5.

The url looks like like this: `/foo-{foo_id}/bar-{bar_id}` and i want the second parameter bar to be optional. So the url `/foo-{foo_id}` is still valid.

### Example

My Route is defined like this:

```
@Route("/foo-{foo_id}/bar-{bar_id}, requirements={  "foo": "\d+", "bar": "\d+" })
```

As you can see, i always need the /bar- for a valid route. Now i can define a second route without the bar definition. But then i have to name it etc.

```
@Route("/foo-{foo_id}/bar-{bar_id}, requirements={"foor": "\d+", "bar": "\d+"}, name="route_foo_bar")
@Route("/foo-{foo_id}, requirements={ "foor": "\d+"},name="route_foo_bar")
```

**Is it possible to define this requirements in just one route so `/bar-{bar_id}` is optional?**

Comment: I actually did just that few days ago but it might be dependent on a version of Symfony2 you use. In my case, I had to match both `/{lang}/{slug_path}` and `/{slug_path}`. I solved with two `@Route` annotations and it worked. Now, naming those the same... that might be a problem... :)

Comment: Thx for your comments. I think @jovan-perovic isw right. It is only possible with multiple `@Route` annotations